# Coldfusion SQL queries very slow

Tags: mysql, sql-server, coldfusion

we have a few coldfusion queries that run and compare data from two databases, one MS SQL and one MYSQL to perform the task of updating the prices on our webshop from our instore database.

The problem is that this query is taking upwards of four minutes to complete.Can we streamline this query at all to speed it up or are we faced with a restriction from our host?

The query -:

```
<cfsetting requestTimeOut = "1440">

<cftry>
    <cfset request.timing = structNew()>

    <cfset getOffline = getTickCount()>
    <cfquery datasource="MSSQLDATABSE" name="get_offlineproduct2" timeout="240"> 
        SELECT p.id, p.code, pl.salesPrice3
        FROM products p with(nolock)
            INNER JOIN productposlocations pl with(nolock)
                ON pl.ProductID = p.ID
        WHERE pl.posLocationID = 1
    </cfquery>
    <cfset request.timing.getOffline = (getTickCount() - getOffline)/1000>

<cfquery datasource="MYSQLDATABASE" name="get_onlineproducts" timeout="240">
        SELECT s.SKU_ID, s.SKU_MerchSKUID, s.SKU_Price, s.SKU_ShowWeb, b.brand_Name
        FROM tbl_skus AS s
        INNER JOIN tbl_prdtbrand_rel r
        ON s.SKU_ProductID = r.prdt_brand_rel_Product_ID
        INNER JOIN tbl_prdtbrands b
        ON r.prdt_brand_rel_Brand_ID = b.brand_ID
        ORDER BY b.brand_Name
    </cfquery>

    <cfquery name="qPriceCheck" dbtype="query">
        SELECT *
        FROM get_onlineproducts, get_offlineproduct2
        WHERE SKU_MerchSKUID = code
            AND SKU_Price <> salesPrice3
    </cfquery>

    <table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
        <tr>
            <th>SKU ID</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>SKU Merchant ID</th>
            <th>SKU Price</th>
            <th>Stock Price</th>
            <th>Price Updated?</th>
        </tr>
        <cfoutput query="get_onlineproducts">
            <cfquery name="qPC" dbtype="query">
                SELECT *
                FROM get_offlineproduct2
                WHERE code = '#get_onlineproducts.SKU_MerchSKUID#'
            </cfquery>
            <tr>
                <td>#get_onlineproducts.SKU_ID#</td>
                <td>#get_onlineproducts.brand_Name#</td>
                <td>#get_onlineproducts.SKU_MerchSKUID#</td>
                <td>#get_onlineproducts.SKU_Price#</td>
                <cfif qPC.recordCount>
                    <td>#qPC.salesPrice3#</td>
                    <cfif qPC.salesPrice3 neq get_onlineproducts.SKU_Price>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                        <cfquery datasource="MYSQLDATABASE" name="UpdateonlineproductsPrices">
                            UPDATE tbl_skus
                            SET SKU_Price = '#qPC.SalesPrice3#'
                            WHERE SKU_MerchSKUID = '#get_onlineproducts.SKU_MerchSKUID#'
                        </cfquery>
                    </cfif> 
                </cfif>
            </tr>
        </cfoutput>
    </table>

    <cfset request.timing.totalTime = (getTickCount() - getOffline)/1000>
    <cfdump var="#request.timing#">

<cfcatch type="Any" >
    <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" label="cfcatch">
</cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Comment: Why would you post all that code..

Comment: I thought it might be useful, sorry

Comment: Post the query and explain plan

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. The query is above.

Comment: Run the query in your mysql client with EXPLAIN before it,edit your post with the results.

Comment: Presumably, by virtue of their primacy, you already have indexes on s.SKU_ID,b.brand_id AND (r.prdt_brand_rel_Product_ID,r.prdt_brand_rel_brand_id).
    As such, there is no further scope here for optimization. (Although a slightly less demented naming policy would be nice)

Comment: Do you know that *ColdFusion* has any hand in this? If you run the query via some other client, is the performance any different? Sounds like this is just an SQL question to me? In general, all CF does with the SQL statement is resovle any embedded CF expressions, then pass the whole lot to the DB driver. It does not SQL processing itself.

Comment: I presume the database driver must be where the query is lagging then. I will test in another client. Thankyou for your advice.

Comment: Also, how many rows are you returning from get_onlineproducts? There's a query nestling in the <cfoutput query="get_onlineproducts"> which will take a long time if get_onlineproducts contains many rows

Comment: Your qPC query is run for every product. Given that once you've run this script once, almost everything will be in sync, this query will return 0 rows for most products. before your output loop, process the qPriceCheck results, updating as necessary. if you need to output which products were updated, put the product ID into a struct , then use StructKeyExists() in your main output loop to see if changes were made.

Comment: Oy vey. Just noticed the loop. Also should get rid of the `SELECT *` calls and just return the columns needed (in `qPC` you only need `salesPrice3`, for example), and *parameterise* all those queries, rather than hard-coding the values into the SQL string! And it's a bit shambolic to be messing your model and view logic in amongst one another like that. An UPDATE query inside an HTML table!?!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, after removing the select * command and specifying the columns, then parametrising the queries I have the query down to 26 seconds. Much much better! I am just working on the suggestion from barnyr

Comment: @barnyr How would you suggest removing the query from the cfoutput? I'm not sure of the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding comment, "How would you suggest removing the query from the cfoutput? I'm not sure of the best way to do this", I suggest this:

```
<cfquery name="qPC" dbtype="query">
SELECT field1, field2, etc
 FROM get_offlineproduct2
 WHERE code in ( <cfqueryparam 
value = #ValueList(get_onlineproducts.SKU_MerchSKUID)# list="yes" )
 </cfquery>
```

You can then loop through these results and do what you need to do.  It's only 1 trip to the database.